# Unlock in-app purchase for a user on iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, ios8

I'm working on an iPhone app for iOS 8. The app is free but users need to buy an in-app purchase to unlock premium features.

I would like to give some users the in-app purchase for free. Can I unlock an in-app purchase for a user if I know the UDID of his device?

Comment: How do You determine UDID from code?

Comment: The users would send me their UDID code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving in-app purchases to specific users for free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753294/giving-in-app-purchases-to-specific-users-for-free)

Comment: Same Question by the same author: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928327/unlock-in-app-purchases-on-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to grant an in app purchase by udid. all apple purchases are bound to appleid's, not to devices and you can't give it for free to specific adresses.

the in app developing guide states:

> You must provide any additional
>   functionality, including unlocking
>   built-in features or downloading
>   content from your own servers.

you can also check the answers there: [Giving in-app purchases to specific users for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753294/giving-in-app-purchases-to-specific-users-for-free)